# FileHashMap<K, V>

Tags: java, file, hashmap, mapping

I am mapping my Hashmap to a file using FileHashMap.

I am using

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new FileHashMap<String, String>("c:/myFile", FileHashMap.TRANSIENT);
```

And then I can use myMap just like I use HashMap. With a difference that everything will be saved to file and when I will remove it, it will be removed from the file as well.

Where I can use this FileHashMap that can use the existing file and use the contents in the file already present. So that if my application stops I can again start where I left.

Comment: what language are you using?  Please add it as a tag.  Also, please format your code.  since it is a single line, you can put backticks around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare it as in your example, you will have access to ONLY the methods available in the `Map` interface.  If you want to access it as a `FileHashMap` with access to its methods, you must declare it as such:

```
FileHashMap<String, String> myMap = 
    new FileHashMap<String, String>("c:/myFile", FileHashMap.CREATE);
...
myMap.save();
```

As to the `CREATE` question, there is no `FileHashMap.CREATE` flag in the JavaDoc.  That is the default -- it will create the file if it does not exist, or use an existing one if it already exists.  Your only choice for non-transient if `NO_CREATE` - Throw an exception if the file does not already exist.

Comment: I tried doing that as well.. Still not able to use CREATE.. Is there any problem with the version??? I don't know if I have imported some other version..

Comment: though I can now use .save()

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take a closer look at the javadoc.
http://software.clapper.org/javautil/api/org/clapper/util/misc/FileHashMap.html

If you want everything to be reopened, why would you make your FileHashMap transient? Create your FileHashMap like this:

```
//this statements opens a persistent FileHashMap, creating it if it doesn't already exist:
//should be this
FileHashMap map = new FileHashMap ("/my/map/dir", FileHashMap.CREATE);
//NOT THIS
Map map = new FileHashMap ("/my/map/dir", FileHashMap.CREATE);
//write a bunch of stuff
map.save();
```

Edit: Whoops :) You need to declare it as a FileHashMap otherwise you can only use Map's methods.

Comment: Thanks.. You are right..But I don't know why when I am using CREATE,it is showing error..